# Django values_list vs values

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-queryset

In Django, what's the difference between the following two:

```
Article.objects.values_list('comment_id', flat=True).distinct()
```

versus:

```
Article.objects.values('comment_id').distinct()
```

My goal is to get a list of unique comment ids under each `Article`. I've read the documentation (and in fact have used both approaches). The results overtly seem similar.

Comment: With values_list you can do
`if self.id in Article.objects.values_list('comment_id', flat=True):` while using values you need to access the dictionary

Comment: @dnaranjo - You could but why not just do `Article.objects.filter(comment_id=self.id).exists()`?

Comment: That's an answer for a different question

Answer (score 493, accepted):

The [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#values) method returns a QuerySet containing dictionaries:

```
<QuerySet [{'comment_id': 1}, {'comment_id': 2}]>
```

The [`values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) method returns a QuerySet containing tuples:

```
<QuerySet [(1,), (2,)]>
```

If you are using `values_list()` with a single field, you can use `flat=True` to return a QuerySet of single values instead of 1-tuples:

```
<QuerySet [1, 2]>
```

Comment: Oh and no difference among the two vis-a-vis how `distinct()` is used huh?

Comment: No, I don't think `distinct()` works any differently. The important thing is which data structure that you want to work with.

Comment: The `values()` returns a `QuerySet` and not a `list`. Although the object returned by `values()` looks like a  `list`, it doesn't behave like one in some cases. For example, it won't be json serializable unless we convert it into a `list'

Comment: @AbhijitGhate good point, I've updated the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: You can easily convert the return from `values_list` to a true Python list by just using the `list` function: `list(Article.objects.values_list('comment_id', flat=True).distinct())`

Comment: As mentioned, if your tuple has 1 value then you can use `flat=True`. But if it has 2 values such as `[('name', 'Jim')]` you can use `dict(`[('name', 'Jim')]`)` which converts it to a dictionary with key-value pairs: `{'name': 'Jim'}`.  Very useful.

Comment: @inostia In Django 2.2 I get "Error in argument:" when trying to convert using `list()`

Comment: @l0b0 the issue is probably in the queryset itself, not the `list()` call. We can’t help with that in the comments here. If you’re still sick please open a new question and include the code, models and full traceback of the error.

Comment: Turns out `set()` does work, so I'm just using that.

Answer (score 108):

### values()

Returns a QuerySet that returns `dictionaries`, rather than model instances, when used as an iterable.

### values_list()

Returns a QuerySet that returns `list of tuples`, rather than model instances, when used as an iterable.

### distinct()

distinct are used to `eliminate the duplicate` elements.

Example:

```
>>> list(Article.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)) # flat=True will remove the tuples and return the list   
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

>>> list(Article.objects.values('id'))
[{'id':1}, {'id':2}, {'id':3}, {'id':4}, {'id':5}, {'id':6}]
```

Comment: So it's a list of dictionaries that's returned in case of `values`

Comment: Just to clarify: `distinct()` eliminates the duplicate elements from query results, not from database.

Comment: Useful for those that use **MYSQL**  because `distinct()` not allowed with this DB type

Answer (score 13):

`values()` returns a QuerySet of dictionaries as shown below:

```py
print(User.objects.all().values()) # Return all fields
# <QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'name': 'John'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Tom'}]>

print(User.objects.all().values("name")) # Return "name" field
# <QuerySet [{'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Tom'}]>
```

`values_list()` returns a QuerySet of tuples as shown below:

```py
print(User.objects.all().values_list()) # Return all fields
# <QuerySet [(1, 'John'), (2, 'Tom')]>

print(User.objects.all().values_list("name")) # Return "name" field
# <QuerySet [('John',), ('Tom',)]>
```

`values_list()` with `flat=True` returns a QuerySet of values as shown below. *No or one field with `flat=True` is allowed and one field must be the 1st argument with `flat=True` which must be the 2nd argument.

```py
print(User.objects.all().values_list(flat=True)) # Return "id" field
# <QuerySet [1, 2]>

print(User.objects.all().values_list("name", flat=True)) # Return "name" field
# <QuerySet ['John', 'Tom']>

print(User.objects.all().values_list(flat=True, "name")) # Error

print(User.objects.all().values_list("id", "name", flat=True)) # Error
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get the different values with:

```
set(Article.objects.values_list('comment_id', flat=True))
```

Comment: This will be way slower than using `distinct()` to eliminate duplicates at database level.

Comment: Also, using set() will force a query on the whole table, when a QuerySet (returned by `distinct()`) will stream data only when needed.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to understand the difference is at the [official documentation on values / values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#values). It has many useful examples and explains it very clearly. The django docs are very user freindly.

Here's a short snippet to keep SO reviewers happy:

### values

> Returns a QuerySet that returns dictionaries, rather than model instances, when used as an iterable.

And read the section which follows it:

### value_list

> This is similar to values() except that instead of returning dictionaries, it returns tuples when iterated over.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get a list of unique `comment_id` values from Article objects, both ...

```
Article.objects.values_list('comment_id', flat=True).distinct()

Article.objects.values('comment_id').distinct()
```

... can be used, but have different return types which might influence your choice depending on the use case.

Using `values_list()` with `flat=True` returns a QuerySet containing single values.

The `flat=True` parameter is used because it's retrieving a single field ('comment_id'), which results in a flat list like [1, 2, 3].

```
<QuerySet [1, 2, 3]>
```

This is more straightforward if you need to check for existence in a list, manipulate the list of IDs, or perform list operations.

This `values()` query returns a QuerySet containing dictionaries. Each dictionary contains the name of the field and its value. For a single field, it's like {'comment_id': 1}.

```
<QuerySet [{'comment_id': 1}, {'comment_id': 2}]>
```

This can be useful if you want to expand your query to include more fields in the future, or if you need the data in a key-value format.

Both use `distinct()` in the same way, to eliminate duplicate values. The choice primarily depends on whether you want a list of values:

`(values_list())` or a list of dictionaries `(values())`. If your goal is simply to obtain a flat list of unique IDs, this is more convenient:

```
values_list('comment_id', flat=True).distinct()
```