# Find different category into all product in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a list of all products which belong to different categories.

**model.py**

```
 class Product(models.Model):
        product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
        details = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
        company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
        category = models.ForeignKey(ProductClass,null=True, blank=True)
```

Category is a `ForeignKey` of `ProductClass`.

Now I want a list of all different categories. I do not want a list of repetitive categories. For that I tried `obj = CustomerLeads.objects.all()`

```
obj = Product.objects.all()


    c = []
        for i in obj:
            c.append(i.item_required)

        cat = set(c)
        return JsonResponse({'data':cat})
```

I am getting error `set([<ProductClass: accessories>, <ProductClass: other>]) is not JSON serializable`

How can I get a list of all different categories?

Comment: Error is quiet clear, `set([<ProductClass: accessories>, <ProductClass: other>])` is set of ProductClass instances which are obviously non serializable when you are trying to send them through JsonResponse. Try to send a dictionary of categories with name, id and whatever data you need.

Comment: can u help me with some sample code

Comment: What does `CustomerLeads` have to do with anything? Isn't it just `ProductClass.objects.all()`? Where are you trying to get this list?..

Comment: @ Sayse Sorry...i done edit.

Comment: Try this: `categories = list(set(Product.objects.values_list('category__name')))`

Answer (score 0):

**distinct()** eliminates the duplicate element of queryset
.

**values_list(*field, flat=True)** are used to return the values as list.

```
 Product.objects.values_list('category__category_name', flat=True).distinct()

#output
[u'Lamps', u'Professional', u'LED', u'Automotive']
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205793/django-values-list-vs-values/41085356#41085356)