# Django - how can I do this query in the ORM

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Hello everybody I'm trying to make this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dashboard_informe inf
INNER JOIN dashboard_servicio serv ON inf.servicio_id = serv.id
WHERE serv.nombre LIKE 'Inventario' AND inf.nombre LIKE 'Inventario%'
```

and I don't know how to make it, I tried this:

```
b = Servicio.objects.all().values_list('id')
r = Informe.objects.filter(servicio_id=b)
```

And it gives me an error: 'The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to '
ValueError: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.

There are someway to do that? or maybe is better create a Store Procedure with that query?

Forward thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the [`__in` field lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
b = Servicio.objects.filter(nombre__startswith='Inventario').values('id')
r = Informe.objects.filter(servicio_id__in=b)
```

Django will convert the first query to a subquery resulting in SQL looking something like this:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM dashboard_informe inf 
WHERE inf.id IN (
    SELECT s.id 
    FROM dashboard_servicio s 
    WHERE s.nombre LIKE 'Inventario%'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM dashboard_informe inf
INNER JOIN dashboard_servicio serv ON inf.servicio_id = serv.id
WHERE serv.nombre LIKE 'Inventario' AND inf.nombre LIKE 'Inventario%'

r = Informe.objects.filter(servicio__nombre='Inventario', nombre__startswith='Inventario')
```

Answer (score -1):

Better to use `values_list()`

`b = Servicio.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True)`

`r = Informe.objects.filter(servicio_id__in=b)`

Comment: Can you _explain_ why `values_list` is better?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205793/django-values-list-vs-values

Comment: Yes, there might be a little performance gain when using the result of `b` in python, but in this case, django converts this to a subquery, with the exactly same sql. It will be something like `SELECT ... FROM dashboard_informe inf WHERE inf.id IN (SELECT s.id FROM dashboard_servicio s WHERE s.nombre LIKE 'Inventario%';`