# Values_list with flat=true still showing <QuerySet [..]>

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to print some query with values_list but for some reason it is still printing  and I need  to be gone and only have the list inside the square brackets...

```py
def resum(request):
    usuari=Usuari.objects.order_by('usuari_id').values_list('usuari_id', flat=True)
    print(usuari)
```

and what i get printed is:

```
<QuerySet [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 50, 51]>
[06/Jun/2019 01:21:04] "GET /resum/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2102
```

Any idea??

Thanks!

Comment: That's how it is supposed to work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205793/django-values-list-vs-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the `list()` function:

```
def resum(request):
    usuari=Usuari.objects.order_by('usuari_id').values_list('usuari_id', flat=True)

    print(list(usuari))
```