# django for loop on html cannot retrieve every data fields for its object_lists

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite, orm

Why for my output.htm file, when I use django template "for loop" tags to retrieve data on **{{ post.firstname }}** and also **{{ post.surname }}**, it shows no result? Hope for help. Thanks in advance.

Ps: below code is only part of the work. This mean I didn't write out python libraries, full html for below code.

```
#views.py

class Student_list(View):
    def get(self, request):
        posts = Student.objects.all().values_list("firstname", "surname").union(Teacher.objects.all().values_list("firstname", "surname"))
        """raw sql => SELECT * FROM l2_OR_queries_student WHERE surname LIKE 'bald%' OR surname LIKE 'aus%' """
        return render(request, "l4_UNION_queries/output.htm", context = {"posts": posts})
```

```
<!--output.htm -->

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
        </tr>

        {% for post in posts %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ post.firstname }}</td>
            <td>{{ post.surname }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

```
student.sqlite3

id  firstname   surname age classroom   teacher
4   shaina  austin  20  1   trellany
5   raquel  avery-parker    21  2   robin
6   lakisha baldwin 20  3   crystal


teacher.sqlite3
id  firstname   surname
9   trellany    abraham
10  robin   adkins
11  crystal allen
12  shaina  young
```

Comment: do you have data in get function? try to print `posts` data and check if it has data or not

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django values\_list vs values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205793/django-values-list-vs-values)

Comment: @Sabil when i print posts, here's the data: <QuerySet [('crystal', 'allen'), ('lakisha', 'baldwin'), ('raquel', 'avery-parker'), ('robin', 'adkins'), ('shaina', 'austin'), ('shaina', 'young'), ('trellany', 'abraham')]>

Comment: {% for firstname, surname in posts %}<tr><td>{{ firstname }}</td><td>{{ surname }}</td></tr>{% endfor %} . I think I should write the html like this instead. But I just wonder why above method does not work (i.e. post.firstname, post.surname)

Comment: @TANYONGSHENG well as you see when you print `posts` you get `<QuerySet [('crystal', 'allen'), ...]>` i.e. an iterable of _tuples_. If `var = ('crystal', 'allen')` and you write `var["firstname"]` do you think you will get what you want? Please read the linked question _carefully_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 posts = Student.objects.all().values("firstname", "surname").union(Teacher.objects.all().values("firstname", "surname"))
```

You need to use `values()` instead of `values_list()` because `values_list()` returns the objects as a list. To access them by keys just use `values()`.

Comment: Thanks you all. I think I understand now. Since values_list() return list instead of dictionary object, thus I could not use key item of the dictionary object to access its value item.