# How to develop a rest api without using serializer in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to create a Student Register and Login Api without using serializer in django Rest Framework.
So I want to know how I make CRUD operation for those api using ApiView

Any one please solve this

Comment: Hi there, I strongly recommend using a serializer. It doesn't have to reflect the model, much like ModelForm, but it will put restrictions around what the API can and cannot accept.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, or even should but first, you need to understand what a serializer actually does:

> Serializers allow complex data such as querysets and model instances to be converted to native Python datatypes that can then be easily rendered into JSON, XML, or other content types. Serializers also provide deserialization, allowing parsed data to be converted back into complex types, after first validating the incoming data

So don't be scared by serializers. Just take your time and learn how to use them using the many tutorials available online.

Comment: Actually I know what serializers are but I have to solve my problem without serializers that's why I'm asking

Comment: Okay then, if you explain why you need to eliminate the serializer, maybe we could help. Do you mind explaining?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DRF then you must need to create the serializers. But you can create the API without using DRF and serialzers.

Answer (score 0):

Serializer is not just for converting json data ,it also used to validate payload. You can use `request.data.get("field_name_in_json_object")` and fill the fields one by one.and for return you can use `.values("field_name")` in
querysets.

[Django values_list vs values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205793/django-values-list-vs-values)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).